# Better way to pull data from modem webpage containing Javascript for use in Rainmeter

Tags: javascript, html, phantomjs

Good day,

Short version: Looking for a way to grab data from a javascript running on a modem overview LAN page in a format suitable for Rainmeter to display on the screen.

Long version: So, I have a Huawei LTE modem with a service that is about as reliable as a chocolate teapot. As such I have the modems overview page constantly open with a Firefox page on my second screen, and it refreshes on its own automatically every 5 seconds or so, but the signal details are small - If I zoom in with the page, they don't fit on the page.

Recently I started looking into Rainmeter and the web parser meter. However, it has a limitation that it doesn't work with javascript.

I then stumbled onto PhantomJS and managed amazingly to put together code to write the page to an HTML file that is then parsed by Rainmeter. I call the PhantomJS command line from Rainmeter every 8 seconds. For the most part it works, but stumbles when the reloading/writing of the HTML file happens at the same time Rainmeter is trying to access the file - that's probably something that is easily fixed.

My code:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.open('http://192.168.254.254/html/overview.html', function (status) {
  if (status !== "success") {
    console.log('Unable to load the address!');
    phantom.exit();
  } else {
    window.setTimeout(function () {
      fs.write('page.html', page.content, 'w');
      phantom.exit();

    }, 1000);
  }
});
```

I've noticed that when the page is open with Firefox, the bandwidth used in the network is very little (Using graph showing throughput), but with my implementation of PhantomJS and Rainmeter, it's spiking the bandwidth quite a bit every time the page is loaded/refreshed.

So my thoughts on this:

1. From what I've read, PhantomJS is dead, so switching to something else is OK, but what I like about PhantomJS is its a single line .exe command which works in Rainmeter.
2. If I can just load the values from the Javascript on the page without refreshing the entire page that I think it would be better.

Thanks for reading.

EDIT:

Thought I would paste in the relevant page sources from the modem, so its clearer what I'm after

First up is the page HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <meta name="csrf_token" content="3NawXult26b2eh87zvVkvEGYEZ5roIU1">
  <meta name="csrf_token" content="ok2fUOoZjv8702fth7vMYJjAzIOZaFEN">

  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="../css/main.css" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="../lib/libjquery.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/changelang.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/format.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/main.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/redirect.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/validation.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/overview.js"></script>
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="all_content" class="body_bg">
    <div class="">
      <div class="">
        <div id="header" class="header"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="content overview">
        <div id="internet_status">
          <p></p>
          <h2>
            <span>
              <script type="text/javascript">
                dw(IDS_internet_status);
              </script>
            </span>
          </h2>
          <div class="cut_off_rule"></div>
          <table id="internet_status_table" cellpadding="0px" cellspacing="0px">
            <tr>
              <td width="256px" height="32px">
                <script type="text/javascript">
                  dw(IDS_usim_card_status + common_colon);
                </script>
              </td>
              <td>
                <span id="internet_usim_card_status"></span>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td width="256px" height="32px">
                <script type="text/javascript">
                  dw(IDS_network_status + common_colon);
                </script>
              </td>
              <td>
                <span id="internet_network_status"></span>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td width="256px" height="32px">
                <script type="text/javascript">
                  dw(IDS_ipv4_status + common_colon);
                </script>
              </td>
              <td>
                <span id="internet_ipv4_status"></span>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </div>
        <div id="mobile_network">
          <p></p>
          <h2>
            <span>
              <script type="text/javascript">
                dw(IDS_mobile_network);
              </script>
            </span>
          </h2>
          <div class="cut_off_rule"></div>
          <table id="mobile_network_table" cellpadding="0px" cellspacing="0px">
            <tr>
              <td width="256px" height="32px">
                <script type="text/javascript">
                  dw(common_label_total + common_colon);
                </script>
              </td>
              <td>
                <span id="mobile_total"></span>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td width="256px" height="32px">
                <script type="text/javascript">
                  dw(sd_label_upload + common_colon);
                </script>
              </td>
              <td>
                <span id="mobile_sent"></span>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td width="256px" height="32px">
                <script type="text/javascript">
                  dw(down_label_download + common_colon);
                </script>
              </td>
              <td>
                <span id="mobile_received"></span>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td width="256px" height="32px">
                <script type="text/javascript">
                  dw(IDS_uplink_rate + common_colon);
                </script>
              </td>
              <td>
                <span id="mobile_uplink_rate"></span>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td width="256px" height="32px">
                <script type="text/javascript">
                  dw(IDS_downlink_rate + common_colon);
                </script>
              </td>
              <td>
                <span id="mobile_downlink_rate"></span>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td width="256px" height="32px">
                <script type="text/javascript">
                  dw(dialup_label_duration + common_colon);
                </script>
              </td>
              <td>
                <span id="mobile_duration"></span>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </div>
        <div id="wireless_status">
          <p></p>
          <h2>
            <span>
              <script type="text/javascript">
                dw(IDS_wireless_status);
              </script>
            </span>
          </h2>
          <div class="cut_off_rule"></div>
          <table id="wireless_status_table" cellpadding="0px" cellspacing="0px">
            <tr>
              <td width="256px" height="32px">
                <script type="text/javascript">
                  dw(IDS_device_info_plmn + common_colon);
                </script>
              </td>
              <td>
                <span id="device_wireless_plmn"></span>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td width="256px" height="32px">
                <script type="text/javascript">
                  dw(IDS_service_status + common_colon);
                </script>
              </td>
              <td>
                <span id="device_wireless_service"></span>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td width="256px" height="32px">
                <script type="text/javascript">
                  dw(IDS_system_label_rsrq + common_colon);
                </script>
              </td>
              <td>
                <span id="device_wireless_rsrq"></span>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td width="256px" height="32px">
                <script type="text/javascript">
                  dw(IDS_system_label_rsrp + common_colon);
                </script>
              </td>
              <td>
                <span id="device_wireless_rsrp"></span>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td width="256px" height="32px">
                <script type="text/javascript">
                  dw(IDS_system_label_rssi + common_colon);
                </script>
              </td>
              <td>
                <span id="device_wireless_rssi"></span>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td width="256px" height="32px">
                <script type="text/javascript">
                  dw(IDS_system_label_sinr + common_colon);
                </script>
              </td>
              <td>
                <span id="device_wireless_sinr"></span>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td width="256px" height="32px">
                <script type="text/javascript">
                  dw(IDS_system_label_pci + common_colon);
                </script>
              </td>
              <td>
                <span id="device_wireless_pci"></span>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td width="256px" height="32px">
                <script type="text/javascript">
                  dw(IDS_system_label_cell_id + common_colon);
                </script>
              </td>
              <td>
                <span id="device_wireless_cell_id"></span>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td width="256px" height="32px">
                <script type="text/javascript">
                  dw(IDS_roaming_status + common_colon);
                </script>
              </td>
              <td>
                <span id="device_wireless_roaming"></span>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </div>
        <div id="lan_wlan_status">
          <p></p>
          <h2>
            <span>
              <script type="text/javascript">
                dw(IDS_lan_wlan_status);
              </script>
            </span>
          </h2>
          <div class="cut_off_rule"></div>
          <table id="lan_wlan_status_table" cellpadding="0px" cellspacing="0px">
            <tr>
              <td width="256px" height="32px">
                <script type="text/javascript">
                  dw(IDS_current_lan + common_colon);
                </script>
              </td>
              <td>
                <span id="current_lan_user"></span>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td width="256px" height="32px">
                <script type="text/javascript">
                  dw(IDS_current_wlan + common_colon);
                </script>
              </td>
              <td>
                <span id="current_wlan_user"></span>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </div>
        <div id="antenna_status">
          <p></p>
          <h2>
            <span>
              <script type="text/javascript">
                dw(IDS_antenna_status);
              </script>
            </span>
          </h2>
          <div class="cut_off_rule"></div>
          <table id="antenna_status_table" cellpadding="0px" cellspacing="0px">
            <tr>
              <td width="256px" height="32px">
                <script type="text/javascript">
                  dw(IDS_antenna1 + common_colon);
                </script>
              </td>
              <td>
                <span id="antenna1_status"></span>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td width="256px" height="32px">
                <script type="text/javascript">
                  dw(IDS_antenna2 + common_colon);
                </script>
              </td>
              <td>
                <span id="antenna2_status"></span>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer" class="footer">
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  <noscript>
    <div class="noscript_text">
      Your browser does not support JavaScript.
    </div>
  </noscript>
</body>

</html>
```

And the relevant overview.js to which I'm after the function getWirelessStatus containing the device signal values

```
var loopTime = 6000;
function padLeft(str, lenght) {
  if (str.length >= lenght) {
    return str;
  } else {
    return padLeft('0' + str, lenght);
  }
}
function trafficStatus_volume(project_id, trafficXml) {
  if (trafficXml >= g_monitoring_dumeter_tb) {
    $("#" + project_id).text(formatFloat(parseFloat(trafficXml) / g_monitoring_dumeter_tb, 2) + " " + common_unit_tb);
  } else if (trafficXml >= g_monitoring_dumeter_gb) {
    $("#" + project_id).text(formatFloat(parseFloat(trafficXml) / g_monitoring_dumeter_gb, 2) + " " + common_unit_gb);
  } else if (trafficXml >= g_monitoring_dumeter_mb) {
    $("#" + project_id).text(formatFloat(parseFloat(trafficXml) / g_monitoring_dumeter_mb, 2) + " " + common_unit_mb);
  } else if (trafficXml >= g_monitoring_dumeter_kb) {
    $("#" + project_id).text(formatFloat(parseFloat(trafficXml) / g_monitoring_dumeter_kb, 2) + " " + common_unit_kb);
  } else if (trafficXml < g_monitoring_dumeter_kb) {
    $("#" + project_id).text(formatFloat(parseFloat(trafficXml), 2) + " " + common_unit_byte);
  }
}
function trafficStatus_rate(project_id, trafficXml) {
  if (trafficXml >= g_monitoring_dumeter_tb) {
    $("#" + project_id).text(formatFloat(parseFloat(trafficXml) / g_monitoring_dumeter_tb, 2) + " " + common_unit_tbps);
  } else if (trafficXml >= g_monitoring_dumeter_gb) {
    $("#" + project_id).text(formatFloat(parseFloat(trafficXml) / g_monitoring_dumeter_gb, 2) + " " + common_unit_gbps);
  } else if (trafficXml >= g_monitoring_dumeter_mb) {
    $("#" + project_id).text(formatFloat(parseFloat(trafficXml) / g_monitoring_dumeter_mb, 2) + " " + common_unit_mbps);
  } else if (trafficXml >= g_monitoring_dumeter_kb) {
    $("#" + project_id).text(formatFloat(parseFloat(trafficXml) / g_monitoring_dumeter_kb, 2) + " " + common_unit_kbps);
  } else if (trafficXml < g_monitoring_dumeter_kb) {
    $("#" + project_id).text(formatFloat(parseFloat(trafficXml), 2) + " " + common_unit_byteps);
  }
}
function getInternetStatus() {
  getAjaxData('api/pin/status', function ($xml) {
    var ret = xml2object($xml);
    var simStatusText = IDS_usim_card_normal;
    var simStatus = ret.response.SimState;
    if (ret.type == 'response') {
      if (simStatus === '260') {
        simStatusText = dialup_label_pin_code_required;
      } else if (simStatus === '261') {
        if (ret.response.SimPukTimes == '0') {
          simStatusText = dialup_help_puk_locked;
        } else {
          simStatusText = dialup_label_puk_code_required;
        }
      } else if (g_net_mode === dialup_label_no_service && (simStatus == '0' || simStatus == '255')) {
        simStatusText = dialup_label_sim_invalid;
      } else if (simStatus == 'undefined') {
        simStatusText = dialup_label_sim_invalid;
      } else {
        getAjaxData('api/pin/simlock', function ($xml) {
          var ret = xml2object($xml);
          if (ret.response.SimLockEnable == '1') {
            simStatusText = dialup_label_sim_invalid;
          }
        }, {
          sync: true
        });
      }
    }
    $('#internet_usim_card_status').text(simStatusText);
  });
  $('#internet_network_status').text(g_net_mode);
  if ('900' === G_MonitoringStatus.response.ConnectionStatus) {
    $("#internet_ipv4_status").text(dialup_label_connecting);
  } else if ('901' == G_MonitoringStatus.response.ConnectionStatus) {
    $("#internet_ipv4_status").text(dialup_label_connected);
  } else if ('903' == G_MonitoringStatus.response.ConnectionStatus) {
    $("#internet_ipv4_status").text(dialup_label_disconnecting);
  } else {
    $("#internet_ipv4_status").text(dialup_label_disconnected);
  }
}
function getNetworkData() {
  if (g_module.wifioffload_enable && G_StationStatus != null && WIFI_CONNECTED == G_MonitoringStatus.response.WifiConnectionStatus) {
    trafficStatus_volume('mobile_total', parseFloat(G_StationStatus.response.TotalTxFlux) + parseFloat(G_StationStatus.response.TotalRxFlux));
    trafficStatus_volume('mobile_sent', G_StationStatus.response.TotalTxFlux);
    trafficStatus_volume('mobile_received', G_StationStatus.response.TotalRxFlux);
    trafficStatus_rate('mobile_uplink_rate', G_StationStatus.response.TxFlux);
    trafficStatus_rate('mobile_downlink_rate', G_StationStatus.response.RxRate);
    $('#mobile_duration').text(getCurrentTime(G_StationStatus.response.TotalTime));
  } else {
    getAjaxData('api/monitoring/traffic-statistics', function ($xml) {
      var ret = xml2object($xml);
      if (ret.type == 'response') {
        networkData = ret.response;
        if (G_MonitoringStatus == null || MACRO_CONNECTION_CONNECTED != G_MonitoringStatus.response.ConnectionStatus) {
          networkData.CurrentConnectTime = 0;
          networkData.CurrentDownload = 0;
          networkData.CurrentUpload = 0;
        }
        trafficStatus_volume('mobile_total', parseFloat(networkData.TotalUpload) + parseFloat(networkData.TotalDownload));
        trafficStatus_volume('mobile_sent', networkData.TotalUpload);
        trafficStatus_volume('mobile_received', networkData.TotalDownload);
        trafficStatus_rate('mobile_uplink_rate', networkData.CurrentUploadRate);
        trafficStatus_rate('mobile_downlink_rate', networkData.CurrentDownloadRate);
        $('#mobile_duration').text(getCurrentTime(networkData.TotalConnectTime));
      }
    });
  }
}
function getWirelessStatus() {
  getAjaxData('api/device/signal', function ($xml) {
    var ret = xml2object($xml);
    if ('response' == ret.type) {
      var signalObj = ret.response;
      $('#device_wireless_plmn').text(signalObj.plmn ? signalObj.plmn : common_na);
      $('#device_wireless_rsrq').text(signalObj.rsrq ? signalObj.rsrq : common_na);
      $('#device_wireless_rsrp').text(signalObj.rsrp ? signalObj.rsrp : common_na);
      $('#device_wireless_rssi').text(signalObj.rssi ? signalObj.rssi : common_na);
      $('#device_wireless_sinr').html(signalObj.sinr ? signalObj.sinr : common_na);
      $('#device_wireless_pci').text(signalObj.pci ? signalObj.pci : common_na);
      if (!isNaN(signalObj.cell_id)) {
        var baseStationID = signalObj.cell_id >>> 8;
        var logicCellID = signalObj.cell_id & 0xFF;
        var strBaseStationID = Number(baseStationID).toString(10);
        var strlogicCellID = Number(logicCellID).toString(10);
        strBaseStationID = padLeft(strBaseStationID, 7);
        strlogicCellID = padLeft(strlogicCellID, 3);
        signalObj.format_cell_id = strBaseStationID + ' - ' + strlogicCellID;
      } else {
        signalObj.format_cell_id = signalObj.cell_id;
      }
      $('#device_wireless_cell_id').text(signalObj.cell_id != '' ? signalObj.format_cell_id : common_na);
      $('#device_wireless_roaming').text(G_MonitoringStatus.response.RoamingStatus == 0 ? common_no : common_yes);
    }
  });
  if (G_MonitoringStatus.response) {
    switch (parseInt(G_MonitoringStatus.response.ServiceStatus)) {
      case 0:
        $("#device_wireless_service").text(dialup_label_no_service);
        break;
      case 1:
        if (G_MonitoringStatus.response.SimStatus == '255') {
          $("#device_wireless_service").text(dialup_label_no_service);
        } else {
          $("#device_wireless_service").text(diagnosis_wireless_status_service_status1);
        }
        break;
      case 2:
        $("#device_wireless_service").text(diagnosis_wireless_status_service_status2);
        break;
      case 3:
        $("#device_wireless_service").text(diagnosis_wireless_status_service_status3);
        break;
      case 4:
        $("#device_wireless_service").text(diagnosis_wireless_status_service_status4);
        break;
      default:
        $("#device_wireless_service").text(dialup_label_no_service);
        break;
    }
  }
}
function getCurrentUser() {
  getAjaxData('api/lan/HostInfo', function ($xml) {
    var ret = xml2object($xml);
    if (ret.type == 'response') {
      if (ret.type == 'response') {
        var hostList = CreateArray(ret.response.Hosts.Host);
        var lanCount = 0;
        var wlanCount = 0;
        for (host in hostList) {
          if (hostList[host].InterfaceType === 'Ethernet') {
            if (hostList[host].Active == '1') {
              lanCount++;
            }
          } else {
            if (hostList[host].Active == '1') {
              wlanCount++;
            }
          }
        }
        $("#current_lan_user").text(lanCount);
      }
    }
  });
  $('#current_wlan_user').text(G_MonitoringStatus.response.CurrentWifiUser);
}
function getAntennaStatus() {
  getAjaxData('api/device/antenna_type', function ($xml) {
    var ret = xml2object($xml);
    if (ret.type == 'response') {
      antennaStatus = ret.response;
      $("#antenna1_status").text(antennaStatus.antenna1type == 1 ? IDS_antenna_outside : IDS_antenna_interior);
      $("#antenna2_status").text(antennaStatus.antenna2type == 1 ? IDS_antenna_outside : IDS_antenna_interior);
    }
  });
}
function getUserLv() {
  getAjaxData('api/user/state-login', function ($xml) {
    var ret = xml2object($xml);
    if (ret.type === 'response' && ret.response.State == '0') {
      if (g_default_password_status == 0) {
        gotoPageWithoutHistory("modifypassword.html");
      } else {
        gotoPageWithHistory('home.html');
      }
    }
  }, {
    sync: true
  });
}
getUserLv()
$(document).ready(function () {
  var loopFun = function () {
    getInternetStatus();
    getNetworkData();
    getWirelessStatus();
    getCurrentUser();
    getAntennaStatus();
    setTimeout(loopFun, loopTime);
  }
  loopFun();
});
```

Thanks

Comment: The only info you need is located at `http://192.168.254.254/api/device/signal`, you can parse that and make whatever you need.

Comment: Nice! - thanks ever so much - don't know how I missed that, but it usually takes another pair of eyes to spot it. It works great now, hardly any bandwidth usage and no need for anything other than Rainmeter - Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Anuga now able to just use Rainmeter on its own - just took posting the relevant code for the answer.